# Does Dapper.Contrib support inserts to tables that use Identity columns?

Tags: sql-server, dapper

I'm using Dapper.Contrib v1.50.0 and Dapper v1.50.2. I have the key property in the class annotated with [Key], and in the database the column  is Identity. When I try to Insert Sql Server is throwing an error that value can not be inserted into an Identity column. Does Dapper.Contrib support inserts to tables that use Identity columns?

```
public class Product {
        [Key]
        public int ProductId {get; set;}
        public string BrandCode { get; set; }
        public bool TwoDScanRequired {get; set;}
        public string CommodityCode {get; set;}
        public string Description {get; set;}
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I accepted the default using System.Component.Model.DataAnnotations, it should have been using Dapper

Answer (score 0):

Changing primary key from [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key] to [Dapper.Contrib.Extensions.Key], solved it!